# Cравнение List<T> на равенство данных

Tags: c#

Мне нужно сравнивать два `List<Car>` на равенство данных.

Погуглил и нашёл вроде как подходящий метод `SequenceEqual`

Вроде всё сделал как на [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-7.0&amp%3Bredirectedfrom=MSDN)

Но если в классе `Car`, присутствует объект `Radio`, то сравнение проходит неудачно.

**Мои классы:**

```
    public class Car : IEquatable<Car>
    {
        public string? Model { get; set; }
        public bool Dead { get; set; }
        public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        public Radio? Music { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Car? other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return Model == other.Model &&
                    Dead == other.Dead &&
                    MaxSpeed == other.MaxSpeed &&
                    Music == other.Music;

        }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj) => Equals(obj as Car);
        public override int GetHashCode() => (Model, Dead, MaxSpeed, Music).GetHashCode();
    }

    public class Radio : IEquatable<Radio>
    {
        public int Volume { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Radio? other)
        {
            if (other == null) 
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Volume == other.Volume;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj) => Equals(obj as Radio);
        public override int GetHashCode() => (Volume).GetHashCode();
    }
```

**Не проходит тест**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CarTest_Equal_True()
{
    // Arrange
    List<Car> cars1 = new()
    {
        new Car()
        {
            Dead = false,
            MaxSpeed = 100,
            Model = "Tesla",
            Music = new Radio()
            {
                Volume = 100
            }
        }
    };

    List<Car> cars2 = new()
    {
        new Car()
        {
            Dead = false,
            MaxSpeed = 100,
            Model = "Tesla",
            Music = new Radio()
            {
                Volume = 100
            }
        }
    };

    // Act
    bool equal = cars1.SequenceEqual(cars2);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(true, equal);
}
```

**Проходит тест**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CarTest_MusicNull_Equal_True()
{
    // Arrange
    List<Car> cars1 = new()
    {
        new Car()
        {
            Dead = false,
            MaxSpeed = 100,
            Model = "Tesla"
        }
    };

    List<Car> cars2 = new()
    {
        new Car()
        {
            Dead = false,
            MaxSpeed = 100,
            Model = "Tesla"
        }
    };

    // Act
    bool equal = cars1.SequenceEqual(cars2);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(true, equal);
}
```

**Скрин с MSDN**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В современный реалиях студия может генерировать это все за вас в 2 клика, причем учитывая почти все. Уберите все, что написали, включая интерфейс, оставьте только свойства, далее нажмите на название класса, слева появится меню быстрых действий (отвертка), жмем туда, выбираем пункт `Создать Equals и GetHashCode`, ставим нужные галки (нужные свойства, реализация `IEquatable`, можно даже операторы переопределить) и жмем ОК, студия вам создаст [такое](https://pastebin.com/BBdN2t5z), ну и дальше изучайте, внимание на `EqualityComparer<Radio>.Default` и `HashCode.Combine()`.

Comment: [Про EqualityComparer<T>.Default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5857711/6808809)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - ого - такое создание круто) `IEqualityComparer<Car>` Пробовал тоже ручками реализовать, так как прочитал что IEquatable<Car> для примитивных свойств,  но тоже проверку не проходило.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Блин, попробовал быстродействие это, реально круто, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка кроется здесь:

```
Music == other.Music;
```

Нужно написать:

```
Music?.Equals(other.Music);
```

В оригинале сравниваются объекты, а они разные, хоть их содержимое и одинаково. А замена сравнивает объекты по их содержимому.

Comment: оО, спасибо, попробую. а я начал думать что это из HashCode, так как он всегда разные у вроде бы идентичных Music получается(

Comment: Добавил ?, так как свойство может быть null.

Comment: С `?` Compiler Error CS0019 - Но буду переделывать, спасибо!